# MariaDB - updates records as per previous row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mariadb

I want to update rows as per my previous data in the table.

Fiddle is this:

https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=fdff8f2de4d5daf5acd7676a1a04e1be&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb

The idea is first to update the p6 column depending on p2 column. If p2 HAS different value than the previous row p2 we need to add 39 to it. Be aware it must start from 836327. So final data must look-like:

```
+====+=====================+=====+========+
| id | dt                  | p2  | p6     |
+====+=====================+=====+========+
| 1  | 2021-02-28 23:35:00 | 100 | 836327 | 
+----+---------------------+-----+--------+
| 2  | 2021-02-28 23:40:00 | 100 | 836327 |  //not adding as p2 is the same as lag(p2)
+----+---------------------+-----+--------+
| 3  | 2021-02-28 23:45:00 | 300 | 836327 |  //adding 39 as p2 is different than lag(p2)
+----+---------------------+-----+--------+
| 4  | 2021-02-28 23:50:00 | 400 | 836366 | //adding 39 as p2 is different than lag(p2)
+----+---------------------+-----+--------+
| 5  | 2021-02-28 23:55:00 | 500 | 836405 | //adding 39 as p2 is different than lag(p2)
+----+---------------------+-----+--------+
| 6  | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 600 | 836444 | //adding 39 as p2 is different than lag(p2)
+----+---------------------+-----+--------+
| 7  | 2021-03-01 00:05:00 | 600 | 836444 | //not adding as p2 is the same as lag(p2)
+----+---------------------+-----+--------+
| 8  | 2021-03-01 00:10:00 | 600 | 836444 | //not adding as p2 is the same as lag(p2)
+----+---------------------+-----+--------+
| 9  | 2021-03-01 00:15:00 | 600 | 836444 | //not adding as p2 is the same as lag(p2)
+----+---------------------+-----+--------+
| 10 | 2021-03-01 00:20:00 | 700 | 836483 | //adding 39 as p2 is different than lag(p2)
+----+---------------------+-----+--------+
| 11 | 2021-03-01 00:25:00 | 800 | 836522 | //adding 39 as p2 is different than lag(p2)
```

I have some ideas from users here like:

```
update dobridol join
       (select tt.*,
               lag(p6) over (order by dt) as prev_p6,
               sum(case when p2 <> prev_p2 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by dt) as cnt
        from (select tt.*,
                     lag(p2) over (order by dt) as prev_p2
              from dobridol tt
             ) tt
       ) tt
       on tt.id = dobridol.id       
       set dobridol.p6 = tt.cnt*39 + 836327 
            where cnt > 0
```

but this is ignoring the 2nd row where I should just repeat the p6 value from first row.

After I update the whole database like this I want to be able to select a period like that in the SQL fiddle query:

```
SELECT 
    p6,
    id,
    prev_val 
FROM (
  SELECT
    dt,
    p6,
    id,
    lag(p6) over (ORDER BY dt) AS prev_val 
  FROM dobridol
) tbl
WHERE dt BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2021-03-30';
```

Instead of just selecting it I want to be able to CHANGE p6 for this period with changing constant that I add to it. For example I want the data for March not to be +39 but to be +50 from last February result. So the new data after this update should be:

```
+====+=====================+=====+========+
    | id | dt                  | p2  | p6     |
    +====+=====================+=====+========+
    | 1  | 2021-02-28 23:35:00 | 100 | 836327 | 
    +----+---------------------+-----+--------+
    | 2  | 2021-02-28 23:40:00 | 100 | 836327 |  
    +----+---------------------+-----+--------+
    | 3  | 2021-02-28 23:45:00 | 300 | 836327 |  
    +----+---------------------+-----+--------+
    | 4  | 2021-02-28 23:50:00 | 400 | 836366 | 
    +----+---------------------+-----+--------+
    | 5  | 2021-02-28 23:55:00 | 500 | 836405 | //THIS IS LAST FEBRUARY RESULT
    +----+---------------------+-----+--------+
    | 6  | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 600 | 836455 | //adding 50 to this
    +----+---------------------+-----+--------+
    | 7  | 2021-03-01 00:05:00 | 600 | 836505 | //adding 50 to this
    +----+---------------------+-----+--------+
    | 8  | 2021-03-01 00:10:00 | 600 | 836555 | //adding 50 to this
    +----+---------------------+-----+--------+
    | 9  | 2021-03-01 00:15:00 | 600 | 836605 | //adding 50 to this
    +----+---------------------+-----+--------+
    | 10 | 2021-03-01 00:20:00 | 700 | 836655 | //adding 50 to this
    +----+---------------------+-----+--------+
    | 11 | 2021-03-01 00:25:00 | 800 | 836705 | //adding 50 to this
```

Basically I select whole March, get last February record and then update whole March with constant +50 to every row.

UPDATE:

After Nick's update

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=aea9f4a4e6be2cc0eafc85c1ed1f3326

But the second query that has to update only MARCH is not working OK:

```
UPDATE dobridol d 
JOIN (WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS (
  SELECT id, p2, p6
  FROM dobridol
  WHERE p6 != 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT d.id, d.p2,
         CASE WHEN c.p2 = d.p2 THEN c.p6 ELSE c.p6 + 50 END
  FROM dobridol d
  JOIN CTE c ON d.id = c.id + 1
) 
SELECT * 
FROM CTE) c ON d.id = c.id
SET d.p6 = c.p6
WHERE (d.dt BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2021-03-30')
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=0f2bb610a3f30fa52eac1fbef7a51ed3

Comment: Yes, this is working fine for first part of the question, thanks. Could you help me for second question where if I decide to add +50 only for March records? It should get last FEB result and add +50 to it and so on to all Marches?

Comment: @Nick is your query valid but with  `where (dobridol.dt BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2021-03-30') ` at the end and +50 instead of +39 ?

Comment: It won't work directly that way; you will need to specify in the first part of the recursive CTE that you want the last value from February as the first value, and in the recursive part you will always add 50 regardless of the value of `p2`. Perhaps https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=4637d845d78368d91fd6a82e6a05b309